# A sparkline from data in every sixth cell in a row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am creating a spreadsheet in Google Sheets where every sixth column is a "total" column. I need to create a sparkline that will grab the value of every sixth cell in that row.

Answer (score 2):

`=SPARKLINE({A1,F1,L1,R1,X1})` would return the values for those cells. The curly brackets treat them like an array.

Comment: Can this be made programmatic?  I want to grab every other column for my spark lines and I was hoping to do it with a function sort of like these:
`=mod((column(B1:B20)-column($B$1)+1),2)=0`
- but they don't appear to work with sparkline (here's what I tried):
`=SPARKLINE(mod((column(R2:BU2)-column($R$2)+1),2)=0)`